# How to Filter DataGridView with DataSet as DataSource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter, dataset, rowfilter

Need some help.

I retrieve data from a Database and fill it into a DataSet using a TableAdapter.

```
MyTableAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet, "Table1")
DataGridView1.DataSource=MyDataSet
DataGridView1.DataMember="Table1"
```

My Datagridview is such, that I can remove and add columns from the original dataset.

I want to filter the DataGridView, so I use the following:

```
Dim dv As DataView
dv = MyDataSet.Tables("Table1").DefaultView
dv.RowFilter = "day >= '05Jan15'"
DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```

### Problem:

This brings back ALL columns into the Datagridview. I don't want it to alter the columns that are currently being displayed in my Datagridview.
Can't I some how get the current view of my Datagridview?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `False`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `False`.

This will prevent the DGV from automatically generate columns when the data source and/or data member is changed.